# JoyStick mapper with keyboard combo support for Mac

Tags: osx

I am looking for an app just like Enjoyable, Enjoy 2, Controllers, etc on Mac (non-silicon if that matters) provides a way to send **keyboard combinations** (e.g  Cmd+Shift+A) from a JoyStick controller.

The aforementioned apps only send single keys/buttons, e.g. Enjoyable is pictured below showing a single key input.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Enjoyable can be modified since it is open source:
https://git.yukkurigames.com/?p=enjoyable.git;a=tree

Run `git clone http://git.yukkurigames.com/enjoyable.git`

I know this isn't an easy answer, but I'm not sure there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just got BetterTouchTool to accept input from a game controller.
It takes a bit of scripting, but can be very powerful.
I now have like a remote to do certain things or a control box using my switch wired game controller.

https://docs.folivora.ai/docs/1500_generic_devices.html

[image: BetterTouchTool Game Controller Inputs]

My script when clicking Parse Device Input/Output looks like this:

```
// Enter your input analyzer script here. 
// Do not change the function signatures
function analyzeDeviceInput(targetDevice, reportID, reportDataHex) {
      
    let reportBuffer = buffer.Buffer.from(reportDataHex, 'hex');
    // the values you see above are in hex format. To read such a byte
    // use readUInt8(index).
    if(reportBuffer.readUInt8(0) === 0x04) {
        log('a trigger!');
        bttTriggerDeviceTrigger(targetDevice, 'Abutton');
    }
    if(reportBuffer.readUInt8(0) === 0x02) {
        log('b trigger!');
        bttTriggerDeviceTrigger(targetDevice, 'Bbutton');
    }
    if(reportBuffer.readUInt8(0) === 0x08) {
        log('x trigger!');
        bttTriggerDeviceTrigger(targetDevice, 'Xbutton');
    }
    if(reportBuffer.readUInt8(0) === 0x01) {
        log('y trigger!');
        bttTriggerDeviceTrigger(targetDevice, 'Ybutton');
    }
    // If you want to get the next report even though,
    // the data has not changed, call this function:
    // bttGetNextEvenWithoutChange(targetDevice, reportID)
}

// Advanced, optional. Use if you want to trigger commands that send data to
// the device, from a BTT predefined action.
// See https://docs.folivora.ai/1500_generic_devices.html
async function executeBTTCommand(targetDevice, commandName, commandInput) {
    log("execute command: " + commandName)
    switch(commandName) {
        case "exampleCommand": {
            // send any hex string to the device
            let deviceResponse = await bttSendDataToDevice({
              BTTActionSendDataTargetDevice: targetDevice,
              BTTActionSendDataData: 'FEEDC0DE',
              BTTActionSendDataReportType: 1,
              BTTActionSendDataResponseType: -1,
              BTTActionSendDataResponsePrefix: ''
            }); 
            break;
        }
    }
    return 'done executing ' + commandName
}
```

This is the controller I used:
[image: Nintendo Switch Controller (wired)]